What is a difference between self or className
Hi everyone I want to ask about class.
What difference is:
class Test:
    l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def t(self, a):
        if a in self.l:
            pass

and here:
class Test:
    l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def t(self, a):
        if a in Test.l:
            pass

And why should I use version with self?

What do you want/hope would happen if you set two variables equal to instances of each of those classes then on one of the classes set the value of l?

you can watch this : https://youtu.be/2uiHcLQ2lLM?si=y7n-2ed4k1gf7n7B

Test.l is class variable will remain same across different instance of class and self.l is instance variable and is bind to the instance of a class and vary from instance to instance

Shamim yea but is a list, so if I change something every object will change it and it doesn't matter is I use self.l or class.l
